# Difference between calling a function in a lambda and function references

Tags: kotlin, function-reference

In the following code (in kotlin)

```
fun greet(){
    print("Hello!  ")
}
fun salute(){
    print("Have a nice day ")
}


fun main(args: Array<String>){

    //val todoList: List<()->Unit> = listOf(::greet,::salute)
    val todoList: List<()->Unit> = listOf({greet()},{salute()})

    for(task in todoList){
        task()
    }    
}
```

What is the significance of using the first way that is now commented (Function references) against using the second way (just calling the functions in a lambda)

As far of results both print "Hello! Have a nice day"

Comment: In this case it's not better. In general: 1) Fewer brackets (in more complicated expressions you will fill it). 2) For functions with multiple arguments you won't need to re-pass them, so you will win some space (and your expression will become simpler).

Comment: It's essentially equivalent.  Use whichever you think reads better.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

you can check the signature by your ide .

:: is reflect operation to get KFunction type from method

val f2 = { greet() } is that : you create a new lambda statement 
like

```
() ->  () -> Unit
```

and then call the inland lambda